# How to recover deleted (?) activity

Tags: activities, search

I think I may have deleted a bunch of activities by accident. Here's what seems to have happened:

1. I had "Activity X" scheduled to occur every Saturday from 6/10/17 to 12/30/17
2. As 2017 rolled along, each Activity was customized as a stand-alone "just this one" edit week by week. This gave me lots of individual past activities as desired.
3. Because I needed to keep doing this through 3/31/18, I went to the entry for 12/30/17 and extended its "stop repeating" date to 3/31/18 and noted to apply only to this instance forward.
4. This preserved the 12/30/17 instance (correct), created the weekly activities through 3/31/18 (correct), but seems to have made all activities in the set prior to 12/30/17 disappear (ARRRGH)!

Any idea what may have gone wrong and how to recover? What I described above is actually the situation for about 300 activities all together (I just gave one example).

We use WordPress and latest Civi edition. 
Thanks.

P.S. We may have a backup, but if this is a bug or something unclear, I want to be sure others know.

Answer (score 1):

Activities have a fairly complicated pattern in the database, where the column is_current_revision determines what the actual version is. You migt want to check the civicmr_activity table to see what the situation in your case. 
Also, if you have logging switched on that might help.
Obviously if you have a backup that might be the quickest fix.

I am not sure if this is a bug, best option to find that out is try your scenario in a demo version?

Comment: Thanks. We do thankfully have a backup. We also have a dev site and will see if we can figure out if a bug is occurring.